# How to setup rpy2 CRAN

Tags: rpy2

When I try to install an r package using rpy2 interface, it pops up a window for CRAN selection. As I select and clik "Ok". It asks again as below

--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---.

It does not allow to select a CRAN from GUI and also ı tried as text entry but did not work either.

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks,

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr("base")
utils = importr("utils")
utils.chooseBioCmirror(graphics=False, ind=1)
packname = ("oligo")
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packname))
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially wrote:

> did you check the documentation ?
>
> https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#installing-removing-r-packages

Without realizing that you followed the doc.

It looks like a change in R since the doc was written. `chooseBioCmirror()` does not appear to change the option `repos` anymore:

```
>>> base.options('repos')                                                   
R object with classes: ('list',) mapped to:
[StrVector]
  repos: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>
  R object with classes: ('character',) mapped to:
['@CRAN@']
```

The following options seems to be changed instead.

```
>>> base.options('BioC_mirror')                                             
R object with classes: ('list',) mapped to:
[StrVector]
  BioC_mirror: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>
  R object with classes: ('character',) mapped to:
['https://bioconductor.org']
```

The following will change the CRAN mirror.

```
utils.chooseCRANmirror(graphics=False, ind=1)
```

I'd recommend to follow what is the current documentation from bioconductor to install packages. Setting the CRAN mirror as shown right above should get you past the installation of the package `BiocManager` without having to interactively choose a repos.

Comment: I implemented the above code based on documentation. It works but does not allow a CRAN selection. As I select and clik "Ok". It asks again as below

--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

Comment: I changed the CRAN mirror from "chooseBioCmirror" to "chooseCRANmirror" as you advised. It works good for installation of usual CRAN packages but cannot install BioConductor packages. And also removed the line "from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector "  because ı realized that this is only necessary for installation of multiple packages at once, otherwise does not support the installation of single package.